# Bootstrap form shrinks as screen expands.

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the inputs the same width as the modal. currently at "md" fit the modal but once the screen expands to "lg" the inputs shrink to half the size of the modal. Am I using the col-lg-12 correctly?

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <legend class="text-center">Contact me</legend>

    <!-- Name input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-12">
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Email input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="email">Your E-mail</label>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-12">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Message body -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="message">Your message</label>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-12">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Please enter your message here..." rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <!-- Form actions -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on this. [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/tj7gvhLp/)

Also take note of the lines `<div class="col-md-9 col-lg-12">` change to `<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">`